# What is the meaning of the error: [method] cannot be applied to [arguments]?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public class Numbers2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number;
        int numberTwo;
        int jordan;
        number = 5;
        numberTwo = 10;
        sum(number, numberTwo);
        difference (number, numberTwo);
        product (number, numberTwo);
        System.out.println(jordan);
    }
    public static void sum(int number, int numberTwo, int jordan)
    {
        System.out.print("The sum of the numbers is");
        System.out.println((number + numberTwo));
    }
    public static void difference(int number, int numberTwo, int jordan)
    {
        System.out.print(" The difference of the two numbers is");
            System.out.println((number - numberTwo));
    }
    public static void product(int number, int numberTwo, int jordan)
    {
        jordan = number * numberTwo;
        return jordan;
    }
}
```

Errors are:

```
H:\Numbers2.java:10: sum(int,int,int) in Numbers2 cannot be applied to (int,int)
        sum(number, numberTwo);
        ^
H:\Numbers2.java:11: difference(int,int,int) in Numbers2 cannot be applied to (int,int)
        difference (number, numberTwo);
        ^
H:\Numbers2.java:12: product(int,int,int) in Numbers2 cannot be applied to (int,int)
        product (number, numberTwo);
        ^
H:\Numbers2.java:28: cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
        return jordan;
               ^
4 errors
```

Comment: The number of parameters in your method call has to match the number of parameters in the method declaration. If you want a variable number of arguments, you'll have to use varargs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like that...

```
public class Numbers2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int number;
    int numberTwo;
    int jordan;
    number = 5;
    numberTwo = 10;
    sum(number, numberTwo);
    difference (number, numberTwo);
    product (number, numberTwo);

}
public static int sum(int number, int numberTwo)
{
    System.out.print("The sum of the numbers is");
    System.out.println((number + numberTwo));
 return number + numberTwo;   // returns addition
}
public static intdifference(int number, int numberTwo)
{
    System.out.print(" The difference of the two numbers is");
        System.out.println((number - numberTwo));
 return number - numberTwo;  // returns the subtraction
}
public static int product(int number, int numberTwo)
{
    jordan = number * numberTwo;
    return jordan;   // returns the product
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are a bit confused about how to define and call methods in Java.

I see that your methods each have three parameters, but the third one is being set inside your method and returned.  When defining a method, you declare the `type` that the output will be before you define your parameters.  In your case, you are currently defining it as `void`.  This tells the compiler that your method does not return anything.  In your case, you want to tell it that your method returns an integer.  An example of this would be the following:

`public static int product(...`

In addition, when you make a call to a method, your call must match the signature of the method.  That means you must pass in the same number and type of parameters.  In your case, your methods are all declared as taking three `int`s as input, but you are only passing in two when you call them.

Lastly, I see that you are passing in a parameter called `jordan`, and attempting to modify its value.  By default, java passes objects "by value" (technically, it passes a reference to the object and the reference itself is "by value").  If you want to actually modify the value of a parameter, it must be passed inside a wrapper object.  In most cases though, you will want to create a new variable inside of your method and return that.  An example would be the following:

```
// note the "int" keyword before the method name
public static int product(int number, int numberTwo)
{
    int jordan = number * numberTwo; // create a new variable to hold our response
    return jordan;   // returns the product

    // You can also just return the result of an operation:
    //return number * numberTwo;
}
```